# Could some explain me how to send email in tabular format using shell script?

Tags: shell-script

Emplyoyee Information:

```
Name    Age   DOB
______  ___   _________
Jones   54    06/12/1998 
Allen   50    06/09/1990
```

I want to see the above output in a table.

Comment: You can send a HTML email with a table. Otherwise, the result depends on the font the recipient uses to display the email.

Comment: How is Jones 54 years old if he was born in 1998?

Comment: please try to ask a clear question. 1- _what do you need_, 2- _what are your input_ , 3- _what are your expected_

Answer (score 1):

Using `html` as RalfFriedl suggested:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jones</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>06/12/1998</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Allen</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>06/09/1990</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In order to send an HTML email using something like `sendmail` you need to have an html email header.  For this I use a temp file to store the contents like this:

```
mailto=to@address.com
mailfrom=from@address.com
mailsub='This is the subject of my email'
curdate=$(date "+%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
html_header="From: <${mailfrom}>\nTo: <${mailto}>\nSubject: ${mailsub}\nDate: <${curdate}>\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n"
echo -e "$html_header" > tmp_file
```

This will create a header like:

```
From: <from@address.com>
To: <to@address.com>
Subject: This is the subject of my email
Date: <Sun, 12 Aug 2018 12:30:17 +0000>
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

You can then add your table to the file and `cat tmp_file | mail -t`

Answer (score 0):

1) As ascii:

```
#!/bin/bash
prtline(){
    printf "%-10.10s %3.3s %12.12s\n" $1 $2 $3
}

prtline Name Age DOB
prtline _______ __________ ___________
prtline Jones 54 06/12/1998
prtline  Allen 50 06/09/1990
```

2) As html-table:

```
echo "<table>"
echo "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>DOB</td></tr>"
echo "<tr><td>Jones</td><td>22</td><td>1821</td></tr>"
#etc
echo "</table>"
```

3) with tbl/groff/ps2pdf. This will give you predictable nice results, but may be a bit more complicated. You would have to send the pdf as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to convert the CSV file into HTML:

Install `nawk` to use this code

```
nawk 'BEGIN{
FS=","
print  "<p>Hi,<br/><br/>"
print  "Please find the Employee details.<p>"
print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1"><TH>Name</TH><TH>Age</TH><TH>DoB</TH>" 
}
 {
printf "<TR>"
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
print "</TR>"
 }
END{
print "</TABLE>"
print "<p><br/>Thank You,<br/>"
print "Team HR<p>"
print "</BODY></HTML>"
 }
' employeedetails.csv > employeeDetails.html
```